# Record audio from the microphone in the default mobile browser on iOS and Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile-safari, html5-audio, android-browser

I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to record audio from the microphone (built-in or external) in the default mobile browser on iOS (Safari) and Android (Chrome) using HTML5 apis and if you know of any working demos?

What I am trying to achieve is a mobile responsive website capable of recording audio notes (voice). This has to run in the mobile browser (Safari / Chrome), NOT in a webview (I know it's possible to do it in a webview).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the getUserMedia() api.

A nice introduction is available [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

Not all browsers support it yet, though, so make sure it works for your desired application.

Comment: Thank to the suggestion. getUserMedia() is great but has very poor support. Chrome on Android is the only one that supports it today. Nothing  on iOS.